# Passing data to server and updating asynchronously

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Basically I have a site where I want the user to input something, have it go to the server for processing and then return it asynchronously, load the contents into a div and then fade it in with jQuery. What is the best way to the do accomplish this?

Currently here is my "solution":

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#output-box').hide();
    $('#form1').submit(function () { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/ParseData",
            data: "{ $('#txtInput').val() }",
            success: function (msg) {
                $('#output-box').text(msg).fadeIn();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

It doesn't work - just returns the contents of Default.aspx. So how do I properly send the contents of #txtInput to the ParseData function in Default.aspx.vb? Also, is this the best way to accomplish something like this? Should I even need to use jQuery to send the data, or should I simply call the function and have it grab the data server-side, put in the information in the result div, and then show it using jQuery?

Also, I've found similar questions (and have asked a similar question myself) but I haven't been able to make it work yet..

Comment: You'll have to understand that methods with the WebMethod attribute are static methods and can therefore not have access to ViewState or other instance-specific properties of your page.  Here's a working example from an asp.net blogger: http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/archive/2008/11/07/using-jquery-to-call-asp-net-ajax-page-methods-by-example.aspx

Comment: You may want to look at http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: I'm not using a WebMethod at all.. is that not going to work?

Comment: ParseData needs to be marked as a [WebMethod] and needs to be declared public/static.

Comment: @DaveWard I would mark this as the answer if it wasn't a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other suggestions, you need to set a contentType of `application/json` on the request.  You also need to set a dataType of `json` to be sure jQuery interprets the response correctly.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'Default.aspx/ParseData',
  data: '{ "strUserInput" : ' + $('#txtInput').val() + ' }',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (msg) {
    // If ASP.NET 2.0:
    $('#output-box').text(msg).fadeIn();

    // If ASP.NET 3.5+:
    $('#output-box').text(msg.d).fadeIn();
  }
});
```

See this post for more info on the .d issue there:  http://encosia.com/2009/02/10/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/

The server-side method should be defined like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static ParseData(string strUserInput)
{
  return "Message";
}
```

This post covers it all pretty well: http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: Great answer. Also going to have to bookmark your blog for future use! Definitely late to the party but better nate than lever.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
data: "{ $('#txtInput').val() }",
```

to

```
data: $('#txtInput').val(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK to me, but you can try to change the line:

```
data: "{ $('#txtInput').val() }",
```

to

```
data: $('#txtInput').val(),
```

Comment: Not working, still returning the entire contents of the .aspx.

I assume my function is fine server-side:

 Private Function ParseData(ByVal strUserInput As String) As String